# Is the WPF PresentationFramework.dll available in .NET Core 3?

Tags: .net-core

I am ready to port a large WPF project to .NET core and would like to know if the controls in the PresentationFramework.dll, especially the large DataGrid is available in .NET Core 3 yet? If it's not available, that would be a showstopper as we heavily utility DataGrid in our project.

Comment: There are already Preview builds so what have you tried?

Comment: It hasn't been really well advertised, but you could use [apisof.net](https://apisof.net/) to search for the specific APIs that you need, and it will tell you which versions of what support that API.

Comment: Jamie, thanks for hte info. Is that from the .NET Framework or .NET Core? Isn't clear. And also not sure what version of the assemblies it refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you refer to class [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=netcore-3.0) you can see that it is available on the latest .NET Core preview [v3.0.0-preview5](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0).

Comment: Heraldo, thanks for the info. Yes, that's the DataGrid. Although it's not clear looking at the Release Notes, is there a way to confirm? Do you actually see this supported in the SDK?

Comment: Hey Cooper, given it is still under development, the only way to make sure I can think of is to update the application to the .Net Core and figure it out :)

Comment: The row map for .Net Core specifically mentions that they are working to port WPF, so I would be careful when updating my application to it given that it is not thoroughly tested yet and tricky bugs might crawl in. If your application is covered by a good automated test case suite then it would give you much more confidence in the migration